# error with the use of the script $ this-> load-> library ('upload', $ config)

Tags: codeigniter, upload

I have this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function load () on string C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ cloud.ikwook.com \ ikwook_system \ libraries \ Upload.php on line 1136 when I execute this script: $ this-> load-> library ('upload', $ config); it may be due to what exactly.

Comment: Please add your code here.

Comment: Please add the code also, from what have you added seems like there is one space between $ and config in "$ config". Please remove that and check.

Answer (score 0):

$ this-> load-> library ('upload', $ config);

I see spaces in between all this I think this should be the same in your code as well. it will be really helpful if u  paste the code.

$this->load->library('upload' $config);